# Compiling SSR ( SimpleScreenRecorder )

Tags: compiling

I am really stuck at compiling SSR

Downloaded from [here](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr.git).

Ran the script simple-build-and-install.

`mkdir: cannot create directory 'build': Permission denied`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The source code should be somewhere inside your home directory (or a subfolder).

Comment: Check your folder permissions with ls -l. sounds like the directory where you are trying to create the "build" folder is owned by root (or another user).

Comment: Fixed it by creating a build folder in ssr directory

Comment: @user299970 can you please make your above comment an answer, and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating a build folder in ssr directory